Fibreglass to Felt roofing join
I'm going to be putting a fibreglass roof on our porch, but the neighbour's roof joins ours. Their roof is felted.
As I understand it, resin is not a good mix with felt as it breaks it down. Will the following be enough to mitigate this problem...

In this case the angle could be held on by screws with weatherproof washers to hopefully prevent water ingress.
To clarify, mineral roofing felt is a bitumen based application for flat rooves in the UK. The felt is usually applied in three stages - a base layer which is normally manually fastened (using some form of tacks), though an adhesive (such as hot pitch) can be used. A second heated layer. Then the third heat applied mineral layer that provides the majority of the protection. Sometimes, this is covered by chippings. This video shows how the felt is applied.
If anyone knows if there is a better way of doing this, I'd appreciate the heads up.

Plastic tends to not hold up well in sunlight, and expands and contracts a lot with temperature changes. Make sure that the "angle" you use is designed for outdoor/roofing use (e.g., UV stabilized vinyl) and that you fasten it according to the manufacturer's instructions.

Their roof is just felt???

Metal flashing might be easier to use.  Can be bent to shape easy and adjusted to fit, where plastic is more unforgiving to adjustment.

Really need a picture to see what you mean by felt. Felt is a term I have never heard used before as a finish roofing material, other than roofing felt which is tar paper, not meant for permanent exposure, only in a temporary fashion, then the finish roof goes over that. You do have the right idea, it is a matter of how the neighbors roof is tied into...

Well, I bit the bullet and went for it ... With Liquid Rubber! It was far easier, less messy and way, way cheaper. Both rooves were repaired for a fraction of the cost of having someone in to repair them.
There were quite a number of issues, including that both rooves had been repaired on top of old repairs; the front roof, which was less than 2m x 2m, had 3 layers to it! We filled 15 rubble sacks with the stuff we pulled off.
The back roof was much better, but still had issues, along the same lines as the front.
We did have to wait for rain to test the seal, then repair any issues, but it has worked - we now have new rooves, front and back for a little over £1K ... we were quoted £3.5K!
